# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '257' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

When I am trying to load file into table, I meet this error:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'students_data.txt' INTO TABLE students;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '257' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

('257' is the first entry in the txt file)

```
DESCRIBE students;
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name    | varchar(50)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name     | varchar(50)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_address | varchar(50)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My table students' is like this, I have add the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but still can't load file into the table.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: If you read the error, it makes perfect sense. The entry 257 already exist

Comment: MySQL is telling you what's wrong; you've already got a record in a your `strudents` table which has a value of `257` in the `id` field... Try changing the 257 entry in your `students_data.txt` file to a number which does not already exist in the AI field.

Comment: can you show the table schema?

Comment: Also ensure that the table is empty before you add to it if this is your initial data load. You can empty it by running `TRUNCATE TABLE students`

Comment: Thanks! I thinks I misunderstand the 'descirbe table' comment, I thought it could show me the whole table. In fact, it describe the field settings of this table.

Comment: you should not be inserting values for `id` since it is auto increment.